# Get size of "list" of keys-values with expl3 and get specific element of the list

Tags: expl3

I'm quite new in latex and I'm trying to build a template for automatic reporting. For this I would like to define a "list" (I'm not sure how to call it in this context) of elements that have a number of key/value pairs and be able to get them back. Based on examples I saw on the forum I built this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{forloop}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Create DosimetryData property
\prop_new:N \l_pollard_DosimetryData_prop

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_put:Nnn { Nx }

% Define DosimetryData add field to token list function
\cs_new_protected:Nn \pollard_add_property:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_pollard_DosimetryData_temp_tl { #1 }
  \keys_set:nn { pollard/DosimetryData } { #2 }
 }

% Set DosimetryData values
\NewDocumentCommand{\DosimetryData}{m}
 {
  \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_pollard_DosimetryData_prop { #1 }
  \prop_map_inline:Nn \l_pollard_DosimetryData_prop { \pollard_add_property:nn { ##1 } { ##2 } }
 }

% Get DosimetryData values
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getDosimetryData}{mm}
{% #1 = node number, #2 = property
\prop_item:Nn \l_pollard_DosimetryData_prop { #1 #2 }
}

% Get DosimetryData number of inputs
\NewDocumentCommand{\getDosimetryDatalength}{}{ \prop_count:N \l_pollard_DosimetryData_prop }

% Define DosimetryData field structure
\keys_define:nn { pollard/DosimetryData }
 {
    Run             .code:n = \prop_put:Nxn \l_pollard_DosimetryData_prop { \l_pollard_DosimetryData_temp_tl   Run }           { #1 },
    DUT             .code:n = \prop_put:Nxn \l_pollard_DosimetryData_prop { \l_pollard_DosimetryData_temp_tl   DUT }           { #1 },
    Samples         .code:n = \prop_put:Nxn \l_pollard_DosimetryData_prop { \l_pollard_DosimetryData_temp_tl   Samples }       { #1 },
    Energy          .code:n = \prop_put:Nxn \l_pollard_DosimetryData_prop { \l_pollard_DosimetryData_temp_tl   Energy }        { #1 },
    Flux            .code:n = \prop_put:Nxn \l_pollard_DosimetryData_prop { \l_pollard_DosimetryData_temp_tl   Flux }          { #1 },
    DoseRate        .code:n = \prop_put:Nxn \l_pollard_DosimetryData_prop { \l_pollard_DosimetryData_temp_tl   DoseRate }      { #1 },
    TID             .code:n = \prop_put:Nxn \l_pollard_DosimetryData_prop { \l_pollard_DosimetryData_temp_tl   TID }           { #1 },
    ProtonFluence   .code:n = \prop_put:Nxn \l_pollard_DosimetryData_prop { \l_pollard_DosimetryData_temp_tl   ProtonFluence } { #1 },
    DDEF            .code:n = \prop_put:Nxn \l_pollard_DosimetryData_prop { \l_pollard_DosimetryData_temp_tl   DDEF }          { #1 },
    
    R     .code:n = \keys_set:nn { pollard/DosimetryData } { Run=#1 },
    D     .code:n = \keys_set:nn { pollard/DosimetryData } { DUT=#1 },
    S     .code:n = \keys_set:nn { pollard/DosimetryData } { Samples=#1 },
    f     .code:n = \keys_set:nn { pollard/DosimetryData } { Flux=#1 },
    E     .code:n = \keys_set:nn { pollard/DosimetryData } { Energy=#1 },
    Dr    .code:n = \keys_set:nn { pollard/DosimetryData } { DoseRate=#1 },
    F     .code:n = \keys_set:nn { pollard/DosimetryData } { ProtonFluence=#1 },
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{counter}

\begin{document}

\DosimetryData{
1={DUT = BST182,    Run = 1, Samples = 1-6, E = 100, f = 3.2e8, DoseRate = 850, TID=100, F = 1e11, DDEF=1e11    },
2={DUT = BST182,    Run = 2, Samples = 1-6, E = 200, f = 3.2e8, DoseRate = 850, TID=100, F = 1e11, DDEF=1e11    },
3={DUT = BST182,    Run = 2, Samples = 1-6, E = 200, f = 3.2e8, DoseRate = 850, TID=100, F = 1e11, DDEF=1e11    },
4={DUT = BST182,    Run = 2, Samples = 1-6, E = 200, f = 3.2e8, DoseRate = 850, TID=100, F = 1e11, DDEF=1e11    }
}

\noindent
DUT 1 -- name: \getDosimetryData{\value{counter}}{DUT}, Run: \getDosimetryData{\value{counter}}{Run}\\
\noindent
DUT 2 -- name: \getDosimetryData{2}{DUT}, Run: \getDosimetryData{2}{Run}\\


\noindent
\text{Length is \getDosimetryDatalength{1}}
\\

\forloop{counter}{1}{\value{counter} < \inteval{4+1}}{
\noindent
    Counter: \thecounter, Run:  \getDosimetryData{\value{counter}}{Run}\\
}
```

It kinds of work, but I can get my data only if I write the number of the element as the following:

```
DUT 2 -- name: \getDosimetryData{2}{DUT}, Run: \getDosimetryData{2}{Run}\\
```

Then if I try with a counter or the returned value of any "function" it doesn't work, I get a blank output:

```
DUT 1 -- name: \getDosimetryData{\value{counter}}{DUT}, Run: \getDosimetryData{\value{counter}}{Run}\\
```

I guess it's because when called in this way it checks the actual "text/string" of the input and not the "linked" value, but I'm not able to figure out how to do then.

Then, another thing that I'm trying to do, that I guess is somehow linked, I'm not able to get the size of the "list" (i.e. 4 in my example).

I tried the count functions of the prop and tl, but I don't understand the returned number, none of them is 4.

My goal is to be able to define this list and to be able to loop through it to get all the elements in another part of the code (to build a table basically).

If someone could give me a hand, thanks!

Comment: Unrelated: If you want to define a key that sets another key in the same set you can use the `.meta:n` handler: `R .meta:n = {Run={#1}}` should be preferred over your nested use of `\keys_set:nn`.

Comment: Your size isn't 4 because you're storing every value in the same property, so you got for instance one item with name `1Run` containing `1`, and another named `2Run` containing `2`, etc.

Comment: To get things working with your `\value` you could use `\prop_item:Ne` instead of `\prop_item:Nn` in your `\getDosimetryData` (will need `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { Ne }`). Then use `\the\value{counter}` instead of `\value{counter}`.

Comment: Indeed using \prop_item:Ne and \the\value{counter} works, thanks! I'm not sure to understand the concept behind though

Comment: FYI, you can mark things as inline code using backticks `\`stuff\`` becomes `stuff`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to split your data structure. I'd put the set names in a sequence and initialise and fill a property list for each data set.

I also made a change in the way you set your dosimetry data, instead of filling a property the following uses `\keyval_parse:nnn` (throwing an error if a value was omitted), as a result this behaves differently if you give input like `\DosimetryData{1={<values>}, 1={<values>}}`, in both cases only the second `<values>` ends up in the data structure, but the name `1` will be placed twice in the sequence storing their names.

The advantage of the sequence is that you don't need numeric names anymore to loop over the data, you can just provide a macro `\DosimetryDataLoop` which uses the sequence to loop over all the data sets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_pollard_DosimetryData_sets_seq
\msg_new:nnn { pollard } { missing-value }
  { Missing~ value~ list~ for~ set~ #1 }

% Set DosimetryData values
\NewDocumentCommand{\DosimetryData}{m}
  {
    \keyval_parse:nnn
      { \msg_error:nnn { pollard } { missing-value } }
      \pollard_add_property:nn
      {#1}
  }

% Define DosimetryData add field to token list function
\cs_new_protected:Nn \pollard_add_property:nn
  {
    \seq_put_right:Ne \l_pollard_DosimetryData_sets_seq {#1}
    \prop_clear_new:c { l_pollard_DosimetryData_ #1 _prop }
    \tl_set:Ne \l_pollard_DosimetryData_temp_tl { #1 }
    \keys_set:nn { pollard/DosimetryData } { #2 }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_put_right:Nn { Ne }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn  { Ne }

% Get DosimetryData values
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getDosimetryData}{mm}
  {% #1 = node number, #2 = property
    \prop_item:cn { l_pollard_DosimetryData_ #1 _prop } { #2 }
  }

% Get DosimetryData number of inputs
\NewDocumentCommand{\getDosimetryDatalength}{}
  { \seq_count:N \l_pollard_DosimetryData_sets_seq }
\NewDocumentCommand{\getDosimetrySetDatalength}{m}
  { \prop_count:c { l_pollard_DosimetryData_ #1 _prop } }


% Define DosimetryData field structure
\keys_define:nn { pollard/DosimetryData }
 {
    Run             .code:n = \prop_put:cnn { l_pollard_DosimetryData_ \l_pollard_DosimetryData_temp_tl _prop } { Run } {#1},
    DUT             .code:n = \prop_put:cnn { l_pollard_DosimetryData_ \l_pollard_DosimetryData_temp_tl _prop } { DUT }           {#1},
    Samples         .code:n = \prop_put:cnn { l_pollard_DosimetryData_ \l_pollard_DosimetryData_temp_tl _prop } { Samples }       {#1},
    Energy          .code:n = \prop_put:cnn { l_pollard_DosimetryData_ \l_pollard_DosimetryData_temp_tl _prop } { Energy }        {#1},
    Flux            .code:n = \prop_put:cnn { l_pollard_DosimetryData_ \l_pollard_DosimetryData_temp_tl _prop } { Flux }          {#1},
    DoseRate        .code:n = \prop_put:cnn { l_pollard_DosimetryData_ \l_pollard_DosimetryData_temp_tl _prop } { DoseRate }      {#1},
    TID             .code:n = \prop_put:cnn { l_pollard_DosimetryData_ \l_pollard_DosimetryData_temp_tl _prop } { TID }           {#1},
    ProtonFluence   .code:n = \prop_put:cnn { l_pollard_DosimetryData_ \l_pollard_DosimetryData_temp_tl _prop } { ProtonFluence } {#1},
    DDEF            .code:n = \prop_put:cnn { l_pollard_DosimetryData_ \l_pollard_DosimetryData_temp_tl _prop } { DDEF }          {#1},
    
    R     .meta:n = { Run={#1} },
    D     .meta:n = { DUT={#1} },
    S     .meta:n = { Samples={#1} },
    f     .meta:n = { Flux={#1} },
    E     .meta:n = { Energy={#1} },
    Dr    .meta:n = { DoseRate={#1} },
    F     .meta:n = { ProtonFluence={#1} },
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \DosimetryDataLoop { +m }
  { \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_pollard_DosimetryData_sets_seq {#1} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{counter}

\begin{document}

\DosimetryData{
1={DUT = BST182,    Run = 1, Samples = 1-6, E = 100, f = 3.2e8, DoseRate = 850, TID=100, F = 1e11, DDEF=1e11    },
2={DUT = BST182,    Run = 2, Samples = 1-6, E = 200, f = 3.2e8, DoseRate = 850, TID=100, F = 1e11, DDEF=1e11    },
3={DUT = BST182,    Run = 2, Samples = 1-6, E = 200, f = 3.2e8, DoseRate = 850, TID=100, F = 1e11, DDEF=1e11    },
4={DUT = BST182,    Run = 2, Samples = 1-6, E = 200, f = 3.2e8, DoseRate = 850, TID=100, F = 1e11, DDEF=1e11    }
}

\setcounter{counter}{2}
\noindent
DUT 1 -- name: \getDosimetryData{\the\value{counter}}{DUT}, Run:
\getDosimetryData{\the\value{counter}}{Run}\par
\noindent
DUT 2 -- name: \getDosimetryData{2}{DUT}, Run: \getDosimetryData{2}{Run}


\noindent
{Length is \getDosimetryDatalength, Length of set 1 is
\getDosimetrySetDatalength{1}}

\DosimetryDataLoop
  {%
    \noindent
    Set name: #1, Run: \getDosimetryData{#1}{Run}\par
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: wow, it's just perfect, it does exactly what I was trying to do, thanks a lot! And thanks for your fast answer! I'll read in detail now to understand your modifications

Comment: @DrStu as always, if you need any explanations feel free to ask in the comments and I'll explain (when time permits).